# SupportMapFragment not loading with Lollipop, but loading in previous API versions

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, supportmapfragment

I have a project with some SupportMapFragment views. For Lollipop devices, all of them but one are showing with no problem. I am sure it's not a matter of credentials, because it is happening only for one of them.

Strange thing is that when i install the app in any device with a previous version to Lollipop, all SupportMapFragment views are showing the map perfectly, including the one with the problem for Lollipop.

Anyone has a clue to solve this mistery?

Comment: is there logcat with problem?

Comment: No problems in logcat, everything seems ok there, but the map view is showing empty (gray) with zoom controls visible.

Comment: Perhaps you need styles for `values-21`

Answer (score 0):

The problem finally was that i was using this code in the parent activity:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

I used it to fix a problem with "distorsion" of the view for Lollipop, when using hardware acceleration. It was causing the map not to show for Lollipop.
So removing it the problem solved!